# How to randomly choose index from elements that are the same

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy, I have two arrays `a` and `b` where all entries are 1's or 0's, I do `c =  a != b`, now I want to randomly choose an index from `c` that is `true` (meaning, an index where `a` and `b` disagree), how do I do this?

Comment: What does your expected output look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `np.random.choice()` with `np.where()`.

Inputs:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
>>> b = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
>>> c =  a != b
>>> c
array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True, False])
```

Example:

```
>>> np.random.choice(np.where(c)[0], size=1).item()
7
```

Breakdown: first take the indices where `c` is `True`:

```
>>> np.where(c)[0]
array([ 0,  2,  5,  6,  7, 10])
```

Now pick one:

```
>>> np.random.choice(np.where(c)[0], size=1)
7
```

And lastly get the 0th value as a scalar with `.item()`.

Comment: aw shucks I knew I had to use `np.where` somewhere hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to achieve this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
b = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1])
c = a != b
# Generating a list of indexes where your desired criteria is met
d = np.where(c)[0]
r = np.random.choice(d)
```

Comment: The for loop `for i in range(len(c)):...` is basically a slower version of `d, = np.where(c)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, just forgot the existence of `numpy.where`